# Is there a library function to replace characters with html-code? [python]

Tags: python, html, replace

It is required in the finished lines to replace the characters with the corresponding html-code.

for example:

```
rules = {
    '<':'&lt;',
    '>':'&gt;'
}
```

Comment: Rather than doing this, consider using something that manipulates a DOM and letting it encode the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since python 3.2 there is the [html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) module with is [escape function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape).

For example

```
>>> import html
>>> html.escape("5 > 3")
'5 &gt; 3'
```